Is jinja allowed in ansible group_vars?
Apologies in advance:  I've been working with salt for the last few years . . .
I want to be able to use proxy_envs from group_vars/all to be able to set proxies in the environment for get_url tasks.
So my task will look like this:
- name: Download something via http          
  ansible.builtin.get_url:                            
    url: http://example.com/
  environment: "{{ proxy_env }}"

And I want to use yaml anchors, e.g.:
proxy_server: &proxy_server "http://squid:3128" 
proxy_env:
  http_proxy: *proxy_server
  https_proxy: *proxy_server
  ftp_proxy: *proxy_server

This seems to work fine.  My problem is with no_proxy . . . I want it to be a list, e.g.
no_proxy: &no_proxy
  - url1
  - url2

But THEN I want to be able to set no_proxy with proxy_env like this:
no_proxy: &no_proxy
  - url1
  - url2
proxy_server: &proxy_server "http://squid:3128" 
proxy_env:
  http_proxy: *proxy_server
  https_proxy: *proxy_server
  ftp_proxy: *proxy_server
  no_proxy: "{{ *no_proxy|join(',') }}"

Ansible does not like this:
template error while templating string: unexpected '*'. String: {{ *no_proxy|join(',') }}. unexpected '*'" 
Is this possible?  Thanks!

From the error, it looks like Ansible Jinja templating is working fine, it just doesn't like the *.maybe you can escape that or something

There is no need to use the anchor here. Remove * from the expression
  proxy_env:
    ...
    no_proxy: "{{ *no_proxy | join(',') }}"

Use the value of the variable
  proxy_env:
    ...
    no_proxy: "{{ no_proxy | join(',') }}"

Then,
  proxy_env:
    http_proxy: *proxy_server
    https_proxy: *proxy_server
    ftp_proxy: *proxy_server
    no_proxy: "{{ no_proxy | join(',') }}"

gives what you want
  proxy_env:
    ftp_proxy: http://squid:3128
    http_proxy: http://squid:3128
    https_proxy: http://squid:3128
    no_proxy: url1,url2




Example of a complete playbook for testing

- hosts: all

  vars:

    no_proxy: &no_proxy
      - url1
      - url2
    proxy_server: &proxy_server "http://squid:3128" 
    proxy_env:
      http_proxy: *proxy_server
      https_proxy: *proxy_server
      ftp_proxy: *proxy_server
      no_proxy: "{{ no_proxy | join(',') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: no_proxy
    - debug:
        var: proxy_env



Example of a complete project for testing variables in group_vars/all. This gives the same results.

shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
├── hosts
└── pb1.yml

shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
stdout_callback = yaml

[connection]
pipelining = true

shell> cat hosts
test_01
test_02
test_03

shell> cat group_vars/all
no_proxy: &no_proxy
  - url1
  - url2
proxy_server: &proxy_server "http://squid:3128" 
proxy_env:
  http_proxy: *proxy_server
  https_proxy: *proxy_server
  ftp_proxy: *proxy_server
  no_proxy: "{{ no_proxy | join(',') }}"

shell> cat pb1.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: no_proxy
    - debug:
        var: proxy_env

shell> ansible-playbook -l test_01 pb1.yml

PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  no_proxy:
  - url1
  - url2

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_01] => 
  proxy_env:
    ftp_proxy: http://squid:3128
    http_proxy: http://squid:3128
    https_proxy: http://squid:3128
    no_proxy: url1,url2

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
test_01



That's with vars in the playbook?  I'd like to put the vars in a group_vars/all file to make them available to all . . .

I added an example of a complete project with the vars in group_vars/all.

Ah, yes . . .  that's the spot!
